# In rails how to allow creation of new class and models at run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, oop, anonymous

I am facing a design problem with respect to a rails app I am developing for my company product right now. My app allows creation of two classes which are subclasses of a parent class.

```
class Coupon
  include Commonelements
end

class ServiceCenterCoupon < Coupon
end

class DealershipCoupon < Coupon
end
```

When you go to the view and you want to create a new coupon, you select either of the two and a new coupon is created depending upon the params[:coupon_type]

In the controller:

```
if params[:coupon_type] == 'dealershipcoupon'
 @coupon = DealershipCoupon.new(coupon_params)
  if @coupon.save!
   redirect_to @coupon
  else
   render :new
  end
elsif params[:coupon_type] == 'servicecentercoupon'
 @coupon = ServiceCenterCoupon.new(coupon_params)
  if @coupon.save!
   redirect_to @coupon
  else
   render :new
  end
end
```

I wanna give admin users the ability to create new coupon types at the run time as well. Say, someone wants to create Repairshopcoupons class. **What changes do I need to bring to the views for example add a new form or what params I need to add to the existing form to be able to create new sub classes of Coupons at run time?**

I do understand that using

```
repairshopcoupon = Class.new()
```

can work. For example anonymous function like this code in the controller can work:

```
Repairshopcoupon = Class.new(Coupon) do
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_presence_of :title

  def self.name
    "Oil Change"
  end   
end

@newrepairshopcoupon = Repairshopcoupon.new
@newrepairshopcoupon.save
```

But I am not sure.

**My first questions is:** What would be the proper flow if I want users to create new classes from the view. What should controller handle and how will it save?

**My second question is**: There are few customers who belong to both dealerships and service centers group. Each group has authority over what coupon type they can manage. I want these users who belong to multiple groups to be able to see respective coupon inventory as well as which users downloaded those. I feel the need of changing my data model so that all coupon inventory and download lists belong to exactly one authorized group but I don't have a concrete idea of what would be the best way.

**My third question is**: What would be the best approach to change my view/UX for creating and managing coupons so that the users of multiple groups would be able to switch between each inventory ? What would be the professional industry standard for UX deign in this case ?

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You should limit yourself to a single question. Especially when they are as broad as this.

Answer (score 0):

Letting the users of an application generate code at runtime is just a really bad idea as the amount of potential bugs and vulnerabilities is mind boggling as your basically allowing untested code to be injected into the app at runtime.

It will also wreck havoc with any class based caching in the application.

It also won't work with cloud platforms like Heroku that use an ephemeral file system which is created from the last code commit.

First off you probably don't actually need different classes for each "type" of coupon. You need to consider if the logic for each class is substantially different.

You can probably get by just by creating a polymorphic association to the issuer (the dealship or service center).

```
class Coupon < Coupon
  belongs_to :issuer, polymorphic: true
end
```

If you want to avoid polymorphism than just set it up as a standard STI setup:

```
class Coupon
  include Commonelements
end

class ServiceCenterCoupon < Coupon
  self.table_name = 'coupons'
  belongs_to :service_center
end

class DealershipCoupon < Coupon
  self.table_name = 'coupons'
  belongs_to :dealership
end
```

Comment: cool! The coupons are subclasses because they do vary in other aspects. The Coupon class is abstract and only subclasses are implementing respective uploaders . This is the architecture I am given to work with. If I only create instances of Coupon class, I can't create different tables for each types. Each internal operation team person working on this app will manage inventory of just one type of coupon.
My main question is how can a user create new kind of Coupons through the user view at run time.

Like they can define new properties of those coupons when they create it through view/UI/

Comment: Also, what you think would be the best ux design to allow a user who belong to both groups. Like do they need to switch their type when I am limiting the access depending upon user types? I feel I want them to be able to switch tabs once they login and see respective inventory. But then again the problem is each coupon should belong to only one group how can I get all the data in the controller so that I can show it in view in different tabs inside.

Comment: I would use a role system where the user has many roles which is used to determine if they can perform an action. You can build that quite simply by using Rolify and Pundit.

Comment: Most systems where you have multiple user types are usually just an overcomplicated mess. RBAC is much more flexible and extendable.